How to style individual cells of FluentDataGrid based on their value?
I have a Blazor Fluent-UI FluentDataGrid and I want to achieve a heatmap effect. Trying to avoid writing any JavaScript - is there any way I can apply styles to individual cells in order to achieve this?
As bare minimum example, this is the grid definition:
<FluentDataGrid Items="@Items?.AsQueryable()">
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(t => t.MyValue)" Format="F2" Title="Value"/>
</FluentDataGrid>

I would like to color individual cells based on the value of MyValue, since this number is already between 0 and 1. I was hoping I could achieve this with only css by using calc() to work out the heatmap colors, but how can I read MyValue for individual cells in the grid?
<PropertyColumn Class="heatmap" Style="--intensity: ????" Property="@(t => t.MyValue)" ...>

Any better approaches or help would be much appreciated, thanks.

You will need a TempateColumn. Roughly:
<TemplateColumn Context="item">
    <span style="background-color:rgb(@((int) (item.MyValue * 255)), 50, 50)">
        @item.Value.ToString("F2")
    </span>
</TemplateColumn>


Thank you very much, this worked! The only issue with this was that the span was smaller than the whole cell, so in the end I had to apply css in two places and change the padding/width so that the background was completed filled:
<TemplateColumn Class="heatmap" Sortable="true" Title="MyValue">     <div class="heatmap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; --intensity: @context.MyValue">         <span>             @context.MyValue?.ToString("F2")         </span>     </div> </TemplateColumn>
